# Keyframes are not working on IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-animations, compatibility, keyframe

I made some research on Stackoverflow and everywhere on the web about my issue with keyframes on IE, but I couldn't find a proper answer.

I can't get my CSS code below to work on IE and I have no idea how to fix this issue:

```
body{
  color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: showImg 1200ms 600ms forwards ease-out;
  -o-animation: showImg 1200ms 600ms forwards ease-out;
  -moz-animation: showImg 1200ms 600ms forwards ease-out;
  animation: showImg 1200ms 600ms forwards ease-out;
}

@keyframes showImg{
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes hideImg{
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes showImg{
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideImg{
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes showImg{
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes hideImg{
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

It works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Has anyone already encoutered this problem too?

Thanks a million in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with? Also, have you checked that you're not seeing it in IE's compatibility mode or quirks mode?

Comment: I am testing with IE 9 & 10.

Comment: Will try IE's compatibility mode. Didn't know it does exist

Comment: Well CSS animations aren't supported at all in IE9 anyway, so you won't get any joy there. IE10 and IE11 do support keyframes, but apparently it doesn't work in either of them inside a media query. You can find out more here: http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframe

Comment: Very useful. Thanks a lot @Spudley

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I had the keyframes within @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait) {}. The keyframes outside of @media ... worked for me